# How can I tell the NSStringEncoding from NSData?

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nsjsonserialization, nsstringencoding

I have `NSData` from `+[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]`. How is the data encoded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the comment above the method in the .h file:

> The resulting data is a encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: and [Apple's documentation for `dataWithJSONObject:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/dataWithJSONObject:options:error:) says as much, too.